# How to add date and days to current date

Tags: node.js

I have use this method in laravel it is working fine but I have to do same changes in node js.Can any one suggest me

`$password_set_date` and `$passexpday` values comming from database.

```
$reqdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($password_set_date . ' + ' . $passexpday . 'days'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to load a date/time library.

Date-and-Time is a good choice:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time

EXAMPLE:

```
 npm install date-and-time --save
```

In your NodeJS program:

```
require(['date-and-time'], function (date) {
});
...
let now = new Date().addDays;
let yesterday = date.addDays(now, -1);  // => Date object
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your PHP Code to JS:

```js
let now = new Date();
let duration = 30;

now.setDate(now.getDate() + duration);

console.log(now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate());
console.log(now.toLocaleDateString()); // The short way if you don't need a specific date format
```

If you want to begin from another date than today, you only have to specify it in Date() arguments.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Your solution also has the benefit of "no 3rd party imports" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).
Do `npm install moment --save` to install and you are good to go.

Comment: I use it on all my projects. For add days to current date just do: date = moment().add(2,'days')

Comment: @SergiNadal: Yeah, me too. It is very handy module for date operations in Nodejs.